# Step-by-step execution of BGE mainloop for debugging?

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm wondering whether it is possible to run the game engine in a "cycle
- by - cycle" fashion.

I.e. a sort of debugging mode where one could
associate the mainloop cycles to keyboard events (for example) rather
than a time interval.

Comment: An older script that would need some editing: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?179336-Frame-by-frame-debugger-2-0-by-Monster-with-scene-explorer

Comment: Yeah the idea is clear and was also the one I had .... I was just missing the overlay scene trick .... thanks

Comment: And if you want to execute your Python line by line, you can drop into the Python debugger via pdb.set_trace()

Comment: Debugging the game engine makes not much sense - unless you want to develop the framework. This is some abstraction layers to low. I developed a library that allows to stop and resume a scene a while ago. You can run the game in slow motion or frame by frame -> so I called it frame-by-frame debugger. You can navigate inside the debugged scene, so you can see what is going on. It helps on any sort of timing problem.This is very hand with physics. But it will not help on logic issues.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to go would be enable the console and to add a Always actuator somewhere with pulse mode enabled, linked to a Python controller using the following "script" :

```
input("Next step ")
```

Then at each step the python script will be blocking the whole execution until you press enter for the input to return.